# Method binding or other solutions XAML/UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have ItemTemplate binded  to my class. The class has a method which returns a SolidColorBrush. How i can bind it to XAML? The class is serialized so I can not just make the SolidColorBrush variable.

XAML

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:GetRem" >
        <Grid Margin="-2,-5,-6,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Bind GetColor}">
```

С#

```
public SolidColorBrush GetColor()
    {
        string ColorName = ReminderColor;
        Color Getit;
        if (ColorName == "1")
            Getit = Color.FromArgb(255, 135, 136, 0);
        else
            if (ColorName == "2")
                Getit = Color.FromArgb(177, 237, 237, 0);
            else
                if (ColorName == "3")
                    Getit = Color.FromArgb(214, 243, 153, 0);
                else
                    if (ColorName == "4")
                        Getit = Color.FromArgb(254, 243, 153, 0);
        SolidColorBrush TestBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Getit);
        return TestBrush;

    }
```

Comment: you cannot bind a property (Background) to a method - you need to create a property in your `GetRem` class which stores the current `SolidColorBrush`. When do you want the `GetColor()` to get called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 months late, but you're trying to use x:Bind to function incorrectly:

You should do

`<Grid Margin="-2,-5,-6,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Bind GetColor()}">`
and `public static SolidColorBrush GetColor()` You can see the link for details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

Answer (score 0):

You should be binding to a property not a method. Something like this would be better:

```
public SolidColorBrush GetColor { 
    get {
        Color GetIt;
        switch(ReminderColor) {
            case("1"):
                 GetIt = Color.FromArgb(255, 135, 136, 0);
            case("2"):
                 GetIt = Color.FromArgb(177, 237, 237, 0);
            case("3"):
                 GetIt = Color.FromArgb(214, 243, 153, 0);
            case("4"):
                 GetIt = Color.FromArgb(214, 243, 153, 0);

        }
        SolidColorBrush TestBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Getit);
        return TestBrush;
   }
}
```